# Is omega a 0 game?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Let $G = \{0,1,2,\ldots | \}$. Then, obviously, also $G = \{1,2,\ldots| \}$. Because 0 is dominated by the other options.

Now let $S$ be the set of options I can 'cross out'. Clearly, $0\in S$ and if all numbers from $0$ to $n-1$ belong to $S$, then $n$ belongs to S (because $n+1$ is also an option). Thus by strong induction S = N and left has no moves.

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, and if I remember correctly, *On Numbers and Games* actually says something incorrect/misleading about this idea.

It's true that the set of dominated options of $\omega=\{0,1,2,\ldots\mid\}$ is $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. However, the usual theorem is that you can delete a single dominated option. By a little induction argument, you can delete finitely many of them, but that's *all* you can do in general.

To quote [my abandoned blog on Combinatorial Game Theory](https://combinatorialgames.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/ii-6-simplifying-conway-positions/), it's not even true that we can delete *only* finitely many options of $\omega$. As long as we leave an infinite bunch of options, it'd still be equal to $\omega$. For example, we could delete all of the non-squares, and find that $\omega=\{0,1,4,9,\ldots\mid\}$.